# Using batchUpdate on Google Sheets API to update text formats

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am current updating my spreadsheet values by using the batchUpdate functionality using the Google Sheets API as follows...

I was wondering if you can also set the format of the cell here as well?  I would like to do something like the following where I have added 'formats' to the object to try and set the text format at the same time as setting the value.

Can this be done and does anyone know the correct syntax?

```
var resource = {  
   "valueInputOption":"USER_ENTERED",
   "data":[  
      [  
         {  
            "range":"Sheet1!G13",
            "values":[  
               [  
                  43516
               ]
            ],
            "formats":[  
               [  
                  "dddd, m/d/yy at h:mm"
               ]
            ]
         }
      ]
   ]
}

Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
```

Comment: I have searched the documentation and cannot find any information on setting formats

Comment: Look into https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'm struggling to see where formatting is done though..?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I can't see anywhere in the documentation which shows how to format that request?

Comment: All that's shown is the format of the request. I'm not sure what you're looking for. You can [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+userEnteredFormat) here for samples.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm still struggling to get it to work, i've tried adding requests: [{ repeatCell: { fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",  range: "Sheet1!A3", cell: { userEnteredFormat: {  numberFormat: { type: "CURRENCY",  pattern: "$#,##0.00"  } }  }  } }] to my resource object but it's throwing the error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON paylo

Comment: Should be a new question for new errors. Ask a new question providing [mcve]  after due diligence. Read the documentation carefully. Don't just copy paste samples. Make the request as per the documentation format. You also should be issuing updateCell request instead of repeatCell request.

Comment: Ok - thank you - I have raised another ticket, I am really struggling to find the correct documentation to resolve my issue!